# Cannot install Broadcom wireless driver on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers

I'm setting this up as a new question because I changed my installation and I thought that might be relevant: previously I was using Wubi, but I felt like that was causing a lot of performance issues (the whole thing ran really slow), so I partitioned my drive and installed Ubuntu 12.04 natively, and it seems to run much faster.

But I still can't get my wireless to work.  I know this question has been addressed elsewhere, and I have honestly tried almost every solution suggested, but it still doesn't work.

My `jockey.log` says:

```
    2013-09-08 14:50:10,100 WARNING: /sys/module/wl/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind wl driver
    2013-09-08 14:50:10,188 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
```

For further information on my driver, when i run:

```
lspcci -nn -d 14e4:
```

I  get:

```
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation CMB4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.